# Why won't InSpec admit that port 5432 is listening inside a PostgreSQL container?

Tags: docker, ports, inspec, postgresql, alpine

## Background

I'm trying to test a [PostgreSQL container](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) with [InSpec](https://www.inspec.io/) 2.1.10, but I cannot get a simple port check to return true, even though Docker, netstat, and psql all report that the port is properly mapped. While it's possible this is a bug in InSpec, it seems more likely that the problem exists between the keyboard and the chair. What have I missed?

## Repeatable Tests

### My Spec

```
# port_test.rb
describe port(5432) do
  it { should be_listening }
end
```

### My Testing Commands

```
container=$(docker run -d -P --rm postgres:alpine)
inspec exec port_test.rb -t docker://$container
```

### My Output

> ```
> Profile: tests from test.rb (tests from test.rb)
> Version: (not specified)
> Target:  docker://8caceaa7e2eefa4a2bf50a58ea1ddf9c927c08d3397e3d9ad5b60d3519971380
>
>   Port 5432
>      ×  should be listening
>      expected `Port 5432.listening?` to return true, got false
>
> Test Summary: 0 successful, 1 failure, 0 skipped
> ```

### But It Should Work!

Everything but InSpec reports that things are working as expected.

```
$ docker port $container
5432/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32770

# from inside container using netstat
$ docker exec $container netstat -lntp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -

# on macOS Docker host; flags are the macOS equivalent to `-lntp`
$ netstat -anv | fgrep $(docker port $container | cut -d: -f2)
tcp6       0      0  ::1.32770              *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    709      0
tcp4       0      0  *.32770                *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    709      0

# connecting to database in container from host
$ psql -V \
       -h localhost \
       -p $(docker port $container | cut -d: -f2)
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did everything right, it is the correct InSpec test and use with Docker!

You encountered a bug in InSpec that is related to InSpec's netstat output parsing combination with Alpine's netstat output.

See InSpec's output for `postgres` container instead of `postgres:alpine`:

```
$ inspec exec docker_test.rb -t docker://1c8162517c22                                                               1d15h master[a5ff79d3]

Profile: tests from docker_test.rb (tests from docker_test.rb)
Version: (not specified)
Target:  docker://1c8162517c229ff8c87ab3e8c909f46b4370d7c63a65c0f973a5c10fdebda800

  Port 5432
     ✔  should be listening

Test Summary: 1 successful, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

In your case, the problem is that Apline's netstat reports a different output then other Linux eg. Ubuntu, CentOS:

```
# netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      999        108791     -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      999        108792     -
```

On Alpine, the inode output is missing:

```
netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

That is why InSpec is not able to parse the netstat output. It is clearly a bug in InSpec. As a mitigation, I recommend to install the `iproute2` package for alpine containers via `apk add iproute2`. InSpec prefers `ss` over `netstat`. Please report this bug to [InSpec team](https://github.com/chef/inspec/issues/new).

Comment: You're right. Using a different OS for the container base and adding iproute2 to the Alpine container both solved the problem. I've [opened a bug](https://github.com/chef/inspec/issues/2890) on the issue.